# Getting data from specific datetime range

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to write a web application that does time series analysis.

I wrote a function in Python to take a subset of a dataset (a Python dict) that falls within a given datetime range (using Python's datetime.datetime class).

In my web application, I'm doing a calculation that calls this function a few hundred times to do a selection on a dataset of around 10,000 points.  This takes around 25 seconds, which is OK, but not ideal.

I've attached an example of my method running on some sample data.  Is there a better way to achieve the same result with better performance?  Suggestions on better frameworks to use are also appreciated (for example, would it be better to do this with a `numpy` array, or to abandon Python entirely?).

The function outputs the amount of time elapsed.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

data_dict = {'times':[], 'data':[]}

#Generate sample data
start_datetime = datetime(2014, 8, 23, 15, 17, 17, 392943)
for i in range(10000):
    data_dict['times'].append(start_datetime+timedelta(minutes = 5*i))
    data_dict['data'].append(i)

startTime = datetime.now()

def data_select(data_dict, time_range):
    start = 0
    end = 1
    for x in data_dict['times']:
        if x - time_range[0] < timedelta(seconds = 0):
            start += 1
        if x - time_range[1] <= timedelta(seconds = 0):
            end += 1
    data_dict['times'] = list(data_dict['times'][start:end])
    data_dict['data'] = list(data_dict['data'][start:end])
    return data_dict

#Example function call   
data_sub_dict = data_select(data_dict, [datetime(2014, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2014, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)])

print "Time elapsed: " + str((datetime.now() - startTime))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is sorted, you can cheat and use the very useful [bisect](http://devdocs.io/python/library/bisect) module. Instead of doing a linear search across the list of data, it checks the middle value, then takes the left or right half -- a *lot* fewer comparisons. If the output data is right, `bisect` is about 800x faster for 10k data points.

### source

```
import bisect
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

data_dict = {'times':[], 'data':[]}

#Generate sample data
start_datetime = datetime(2014, 8, 23, 15, 17, 17, 392943)
for i in range(10000):
    data_dict['times'].append(start_datetime+timedelta(minutes = 5*i))
    data_dict['data'].append(i)

startTime = datetime.now()

def data_select_search(data_dict, time_range):
    start = 0
    end = 1
    times = data_dict['times']
    for x in times:
        if x - time_range[0] < timedelta(seconds = 0):
            start += 1
        if x - time_range[1] <= timedelta(seconds = 0):
            end += 1
    # print 'search:',start,end
    data_dict['times'] = list(data_dict['times'][start:end])
    data_dict['data'] = list(data_dict['data'][start:end])
    return data_dict

def data_select_bisect(data_dict, time_range):
    times = data_dict['times']
    start = bisect.bisect_left(times, time_range[0])
    end = bisect.bisect_right(times, time_range[1], lo=start) + 1
    # print 'bisect:',start,end
    return dict(
        times=data_dict['times'][start:end],
        data=data_dict['data'][start:end],
        )

drange = [
        datetime(2014, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        datetime(2014, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ]
data_sub_dict = data_select_search(data_dict.copy(), drange)
_dict2 = data_select_bisect(data_dict.copy(), drange)

import timeit
mysetup = "from __main__ import data_select_bisect, data_select_search, data_dict, drange"
num = 100

print('search:', timeit.timeit(
    "data_select_search(data_dict.copy(), drange)", 
    setup=mysetup,
    number=num
    ))
print('bisect:', timeit.timeit(
    "data_select_bisect(data_dict.copy(), drange)", 
    setup=mysetup,
    number=num,
    ))
```

### output

```
('search:', 1.2735650539398193)
('bisect:', 0.0015599727630615234)
```